# How to upload image with entity class in web api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, webapi

How I can upload image with entity class in web api c# for example :

```
    [Route("api/Prescription/Create/")]
    public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]Prescription prescription)
    {
      if (prescription.prescription_image != null)
       {
        Console.WriteLine(prescription.prescription_image.FileName);
        // do any process for the image
       }
    }
```

Comment: if you need post other parameters, you can post from the route.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files with entity type! 
you can upload files to API with the `POST` method.

Notice: if you need post other parameters, you can post from the route

```
        [HttpPost, Route("api/Prescription/Create/{someParameter}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(int someParameter)
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            var files = provider.Contents;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
              var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            }
         }
```

and you can test it with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).